# How to get response from mapreduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

How can I get response from my Map Reduce job?

I have submitted job input like this in my java program.

```
conf.set("key1", somevalue);conf.set("key2", somevalue);
Job job = new Job(conf, jobId);
if (job != null) {
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
```

this job has executed successfully, Now at job completion(its a map only job) I want to return some value.
I am going to use

```
protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException { // How can I set value here }
```

I want to return last/largest key Mapper has used or Is there any way to get lastkey from InputSplit?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

However, this might not be the best solution, but as a workaround you may store the per task max value in a `counter` which you can
retrieve in the jobrunner class. Then iterate over them and select the largest value.
E.g:

**Mapper:**

```
private long num = 0L;

@Override
protected void map(...) {
  ...
  num++;
  ...
}

@Override 
public void cleanup(Context context) {
  context.getCounter("MaxValue", "task_" + 
    context.getTaskAttemptID().getTaskID().getId()).increment(num);
}
```

**JobRunner**

Select the max value after the job has finished:

```
...
long max = 0;
CounterGroup group = job.getCounters().getGroup("MaxValue");
for (Counter c : group) {
  long val = c.getValue();
  if (val > max) {
    max = val;
  }
}
...
```

Comment: For any downvoter:  I marked that this is just a workaround (meaning a hack) not a best practice written in stone

Answer (score 2):

To get the max value you should declare an instance variable and use it to hold the largest value the mapper() method has seen so far.  You may need some way to indicate that no value has been seen, yet.  When the cleanup() method is finally called the variable holds the value you want.

Returning this value is a bit more difficult.  Hadoop workflow engines all use variant of the following approach to passing data between hadoop jobs.  You can use this approach to pass the max value to whoever needs it when the job is done.  The hack/kludge involves using a well-known hdfs directory (could be passed in) and the taskid to build a unique, discoverable filename to hold the value.  Use HDFS file io API's to write the value out.